# Configure Jenkins to build a React App without access to central NPM repository and without Nexus

Tags: jenkins, deployment

I need to configure Jenkins to build and deploy a React application. The main problem I have is that I don't have access to the central NPM repository in any way except the development machine.

Jenkins Controller has internet access, but the Agent is running in a internal network.
So in the installation phase, when running 'npm install', I get errors, because the Agent can't download the packages.

Initially I was thinking of using Nexus to setup a proxy NPM repository, but because of company IT rules, this seems to be a very long process and will take some amount of time and I am looking for a short term temporary solution.

Other possibilities that I checked were using something like Verdaccio to create a private repository from the Project and provide it to Jenkins or running the build in the Jenkins Controller, but I don't have any experience with both ways and I am looking for all available/possible solutions.

Any other proposals, solutions, or recommendations?